# Confused with delete keyword operation in C++

Tags: c++, new-operator, factory-pattern, virtual-functions, delete-operator

I would like to know how delete works?
In main function I have deleted the `cfact` `object`. But still the `cfact->Hello()` works instead of throwing an error.
While debugging I found while delete happens, `cfact` releases the memory. as soon as `factory* c2fact = newfun.Newfun("c2_fact");` line executes `cfact` gets some memory location.

```
class factory{

public:
    virtual void Hello() = 0;
};
class c_fact: public factory
{
public:
    void Hello(){
    cout << "class c_fact: public factory"<<endl;
    }
};
class c2_fact: public factory
{
public:
    void Hello(){
    cout << "class c2_fact: public factory"<<endl;
    }
};

class callFun{
public:
    virtual factory* Newfun(string data)
    {
        if(data == "c_fact")
            {return new c_fact;}
        else
            {return new c2_fact;}
    }
};
class newFun:public callFun{
public:
    factory* Newfun(string data)
    {
        if(data == "c_fact")
            {return new c_fact;}
        else if (data == "c2_fact")
            {return new c2_fact;}
    }
};
int main()
{
    newFun newfun;
    factory* cfact = newfun.Newfun("c_fact");
    delete cfact;                              //Deleted the instance
    factory* c2fact = newfun.Newfun("c2_fact");
    cfact->Hello();//Still it prints the output
    c2fact->Hello();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen? You are calling a function on a deleted object. This is undefined behaviour, and anything could happen, including printing the output.

Comment: @PeterWood: I want `cfact->Hello();` to fail. Accidentally I saw this behavior. So, I could not able to understand I thought of to ask.

Comment: You should use virtual destructors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`delete` doesn't actually invalidate what it points to. It just **tells the OS that the memory can be used for something else** and that the program doesn't need it anymore.

If it not overwritten by other data your data will still be in memory and will still be **accessible**. This is a cause of many bugs that go undetected during development phase and later show up.

The fact that is is working now doesn't mean it will always work. For example if you move the code to another machine or if you restart your computer the code might segfault.

It is always a good practice to set pointers to `NULL` after `delete`. Or even better use `smart pointers`.

Comment: `delete` could invalidate what it points to, it just doesn't have to according to the standard. It's an implementation detail.

Comment: Also delete doesn't return the memory to the OS, it only returns it to the applications memory pool, which may not be the same. That's also an implementation detail. it would be a bad implementation though, if delete directly goes through to OS memory handling in a normal user space environment.

Answer (score 2):

This is undefined behavior, most likely this works because the method `Hello` is not using any of the classes variables and thus is not using the `this` pointer. Trying outputting `this` in `Hello` and you should see an invalid pointer after the call to `delete`:

```
std::cout << std::hex << this << << std::endl ;
```

In my test case it comes back as `0` after `delete`

Answer (score 1):

Dereferencing a deleted pointer is *undefined behaviour*. That means anything can happen, including the program appearing to "work". You cannot rely on any such behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

When you delete the memory it is released. however, the content is usually not changed, so anything that is written in that memory is still there after the delete, but you don't know how long it will stay, as other functions can grab it and overwrite it with their own data.

On some compilers, when compiling in debug mode, the memory is marked, so that you can detect such errors as you did by reusing the deleted pointer. However that is not necessarily the default. So you should never reuse a pointer that was deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I can't comment...
I compiled your code and you can observe that c2fact replaces the cfact you just destroyed (the output is

> class c2_fact: public factory
>
> class c2_fact: public factory
> )

BTW if you put "cfact->Hello();" before you create your c2fact, the program may crash (which is what you seem to wish) because the mem blocks are not affected to any object. Note that this behavior may change depending on the memory monitoring and other running processes.

Comment: They keyword is "... MAY crash ...". since this program is rather short and doesn't do much, chances are it will work unnoticed. Of course it is compiler and even library dependent. It might crash immediatly, or it can work for years in production code and let your code crash in a totally different place.

Comment: Arf I can't upvote your comment... And in fact maybe I should correct myself : "if you put "cfact->Hello();" before you create your c2fact, the program WILL crash". I just tested it using Win7 ;) and mingw, anuone to test it using other OS/compilers?

Comment: Just tried it with gcc 3.4. using cygwin on Windows XP under eclipse and it does NOT crash. compiler options can also matter. If you put -g it might behave different then using .i.e -O2 or whatever. I also tried your suggested change and it doesn't crash. :)

Comment: Thanks for this clarification... Now I want to try these compiler options I never heard of before!

Comment: -g is to include debug information in the binary, so the debugger gives you the sourceline and variable names. -O2 is an optimiziation level so the compiler tries to optimize the code where possible. However using -g and -O<x> together is not recommendable.

Comment: Still can't upvote but I mean it... Got to grab a few badges ;)